# Why is this post marked "Post is related to a rapidly changing event".?

Tags: support

I see that this question: [QGIS Server limitations ?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/56738) has a notice under it saying "Post is related to a rapidly changing event".

I have gone through the following two questions:

1. [What does the "Current event" post notice mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107269/what-does-the-current-event-post-notice-mean)
2. [What are these notices under my post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165006/what-are-these-notices-under-my-post)

I am still not sure what the notice means. This raises the following the questions:

- Why was this notice attached to the question?
- What point is meant to be conveyed to the users of this site, when they see the notice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I attached the post notice because QGIS Server is evolving quite fast and any limitation that we find today might already be history tomorrow.

My hope is that users who see this post notice realize that the answers can very well be outdated. Most likely they won't - but at least I tried.

Comment: So to clarify, it is not for the current users, but for users who see it in the future?

Comment: Yes that's my interpretation of the notice but if others disagree I'm happy to discuss its usage.

Comment: That was exactly my understanding based on the 2 linked discussions; I just wanted to be sure that I have understood correctly.